# Logistic regression (binomial) in svyglm, using R, calculating odds ratio and confidence interval

Tags: r

I am calculating the odds ratio of a binomial logistic regression model using exp, is there a function to calculate the 95% confidence intervals?

```
    model_1 <-svyglm(formula = ACV_COVIDCAR_NEW_1~DMV_H_OPMDCD_combined_factor, design = 
    data2, family = "binomial" (link="logit"))
    summary(model_1)
    exp(coef(model_1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes - `survey::confint.svyglm`.